# What RewriteRule shall I add to my existing rules to fix this?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My page has 2 languages (in the near future will be 3). It has this structure on inner pages:

```
domain.com/en/page (where page is page.php in main root)
```

and the main page can be accessed through `domain.com` or `domain.com/en/`

In my server I have all the files in the main root, and one folder named articles, where inside there are some other files.

When I access the index of folder articles index like `domain.com/en/articles` it is ok.

but when I access it like `domain.com/articles` it takes me to 404 page.

How can I still open that folder without `/en/` or `/el/` in front of it?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(en|el)/articles$ articles/index.php?lang=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^(en|el)(/)?$ index.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(en|el)/(.*)?$ $2.php?lang=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Also, because I am new in htaccess please take a look at my overall code and tell me for any improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have rules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/?$ articles/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(en|el)/articles$ articles/index.php?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(en|el)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(en|el)/(.+)$ $2.php?lang=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi there, it works, thank you! One question. If I visit domain.com/articles it puts a trailing slash, is this because it is a folder?

Comment: Yes that's correct. `mod_dir` module adds a trailing slash in front of directories.